# Can I write doxygen alias similar to @code or @verbatim?

Tags: doxygen

I need an alias to mark command-line code, set on a black background with white text, to be used like this:

```
@cmd
C:\temp>echo Hello, world!
Hello, world!

C:\temp>
@endcmd
```

Ordinary doxygen's aliases can't do this (multiline, nested "\temp"), but `@code` and `@verbatim` can. However, I can't use them because they are formatted as a white background with black text, so overwriting pre.fragment class with a custom CSS is not correct.

Any ideas?

**UPD**:
Comments showed how bad my English is...

Well, try again. Regular doxygen's features like HTML and XML works as shown bellow:

```
    cpp file                       doxygen produced index.html
/**
@mainpage main               |  
<pre>                        | <pre>C:&gt;echo Hello, world! 
C:\temp>echo Hello, world!   | Hello, world!</pre>  
Hello, world!                |
                             |
C:\temp>                     | <pre>C:&gt;</pre>
</pre>                       |
*/                           |
```

in the log:

```
/tmp/index.h:3: warning: Found unknown command `\temp'
/tmp/index.h:6: warning: Found unknown command `\temp'
```

"code" and "verbatim" works different! Feel the difference:

```
  cpp file                       doxygen produced index.html
/**
@mainpage main               |
@verbatim                    | <div class="fragment">
C:\temp>echo Hello, world!   | <pre class="fragment">C:\temp&gt;echo Hello, world!
Hello, world!                | Hello, world!
                             |
C:\temp>                     | C:\temp&gt;
@endverbatim                 | </pre>
*/                           | <div>
```

The question is: Can I write alias, that will work like "code" or "verbatim". Is it clean now?

Answer (score 1):

What about just using and HTML div with your own CSS markup added to the Doxygen css file.  It seems about the same amount of typing.

Comment: No, it is not. For example. if I define the following way: ALIASES += cmd="<div STYLE=\"...\"><pre>" ALIASES+=endcmd="</pre></div>", I'll get: <div ...><pre>C:>echo Hello, world!\nHello, world!</pre></div>\n<div ... ><pre>C:</pre></div>

Comment: Doxygen allows HTML in the documentation so you can have <div class="my_cmd_style"> C:\temp> ... </div> in your comment.   Once efine 'my_cmd_style' in the CSS file for the project you're done.

Comment: I know about HTML. But, repeat again, there are \n\n sequence in the text and "\" symbol. \n\n will divide text into parts and "\temp" will  be treated as nested alias and will be excluded from the output. This does not happen, when you use \code \endcode, or \verbatim \endverbatim.

Comment: You could use the `<pre>` tag instead of the `<div>` tag.

Comment: @hoxnox Sorry, just saw the `div` tag! Anyway, I tried `C:\temp>echo Hello, world!` wrapped in a `pre` tag and I get the text `C:\temp>echo Hello, world!`, as expected - the `pre` tag won't strip out `\t`.

Comment: @Chris, and what about new line? Does doxygen interpret the text as **two** different tagged pieces, or as **one**? E.g. `<pre>C:\temp>echo Hello, world! 
Hello, world! C:\temp></pre>` or `<pre>C:\temp>echo Hello, world!
Hello, world!</pre><pre>C:\temp></pre>`

Comment: I think you are confusing the role of doxygen and HTML. All doxygen does is try to establish the relationship between functions/classes in your source code and then writes a bit of HTML (actually XML) for each. The HTML is then interpreted by your browser or whatever you use to view the documentation. Read up on the **HTML** `<pre>` tag to see how inputs are interpreted - this is nothing to do with doxygen.

Comment: @Chris, I know HTML well, but English - not. =) I tried to rephrase the question and wrote the example...

Answer (score 1):

*This answer summarises some the the comments in Paul Joireman's answer.*

Paul Joireman's answer is the way to go. Define two aliases in your doxygen configuration file:

```
ALIASES += "mycode=<div class="myfragment"><pre class=myfragment>"
ALIASES += "endmycode=</pre></div>"
```

and the wrap your code example in `\mycode` and `\endmycode` statements. For example, your C++ file could look something like

```
/** \mainpage main
 * \mycode
 * C:\\temp>echo Hello, World!
 * Hello, World!
 *
 * \endmycode
*/
```

which yields the following corresponding doxygen HTML output:

```
<div class="myfragment>"><pre class="myfragment>">
 C:\temp&gt;echo Hello, World!
 Hello, World!</pre></div>
```

(I'm not sure why there are `>`'s in the `class="myfragments>"` parts). You will need to format the `myfragments` class in the CSS file.

The one additional thing in the above C++ code that wasn't mentioned in the comments is the use of the escaped backslash `\\` in the code example.

Comment: Thnaks, cap. =) Try exactly my example and set black background, if you didn't understand the problem of wrapping <pre> (you've got [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/804/screenshotfilename.jpg) ). And, of cource escaping every "\" symbol is not the way out. All problems, described in the question are not solved.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Doxygen still interprets the newline as a way to separate the `<pre>` blocks. For example, consider `<pre>1\n\n2\n\n3</pre>`. Doxygen's generated HTML would be `<pre>1</pre><pre>2</pre><pre>3</pre>` which is annoying. This doesn't fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only wayout i found is

```
ALIASES += cmd="<div class=\"cmd\">@verbatim"
ALIASES += endcmd="@endverbatim</div>"
```

Where, CSS "cmd" class is set in your own stylesheet. May be:

> .cmd {    color:#e3e3e3;  background-color:#222222; }